# LINQ for dynamic columns in a table in c#

Tags: c#, linq

I hava table with multiple vehicle columns 
[image]

My corresponding SQL Query is

```
sQuery = "Select * from Vehicle where " + variant + "='Y'";
```

How can I write the same query in LINQ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dynamic where condition in LINQ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5674639/dynamic-where-condition-in-linq)

Answer (score 2):

You can build lambda expression dynamically by using `System.Linq.Expression` namespace and pass it to `Where` method.

For example:

```
public IQueryable<Vehicle> GetAccounts(string variant)
{
    // Build equivalent lambda to 'param => param.{variant} == "Y"'

    // This is lambda parameter
    var param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Vehicle));

    // This is lambda body (comparison)
    var body = Expression.Equal(
        // Access property {variant} of param
        Expression.Property(param, typeof(Vehicle).GetProperty(variant)),
        // Constant value "Y"
        Expression.Constant("Y")
    );

    // Build lambda using param and body defined above
    var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<Vehicle, bool>>(body, param);

    // Use created lambda in query
    return VehicleDatatable.Where(lambda);
}
```

Another idea is to convert query a bit.
You can realize same work using following query:

```
sQuery = "Select * from Vehicle where (Tracks+Cars+Utility) LIKE '" + value + "'";
```

Where `value` is 'Y__' or '*Y*' or '__Y' depending on which vehicle type you want to query. It's definitely not most effective, but that is pretty easy to convert to linq.

Answer (score 2):

Build your query:

```
var query = Vehiclelist;
if (column == "Trucks")
{
    query = query.Where(q => q.Trucks=="Y");
}
else if (column == "Cars")
{
    query = query.Where(q => q.Cars=="Y");
}
else if (column == "Utility")
{
    query = query.Where(q => q.Utility=="Y");
}
```

This approach is more maintainable, more testable. You have strong-typed expressions and transparent filters.

Comment: I like this one even it is not literally fit OP's requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Vehiclelist.Where(q => q.Trucks=="Y" || q.Cars=="Y" || q.Utility=="Y");
```

Comment: This wont solve my problem. I get the column name as a variable. And I have to query for that column only.

Answer (score 0):

using lambda expression :

```
VehicleDatatable.AsEnumerable().Where(q=>q.Trucks=="Y" || q.Cars=="Y" || q.Utility=="Y");
```

Another way

```
(from d in VehicleDatatable.AsEnumerable() where string.compare(d["Trucks"],"Y")==0 select d)
```

Comment: replace `Select` with `Where`

Answer (score 0):

This may also be another approach:

```
PropertyInfo pi = typeof(Vehicles).GetProperty(vehVariant);
var services = context.Vehicles.ToList();

services = services.Where(item => pi.GetValue(item).ToString().Trim() == "Y").ToList();
```

Happy Coding.